# Spring boot security always shows the login form after correct details entered

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I've setup a spring boot web application and followed the instructions on this link https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/ to setup a basic login form.

When I run the application the login form appears, but when I enter the correct login details the login form appears again. It seems to me like spring isn't picking up that the login form has been completed, and as the login form submits back to itself.

Here's my security configuration;

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/admin/account/login")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/admin/dashboard")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .logout()
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/admin/account/logout"))
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/admin/account/login");

        http.exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/admin/account/forbidden");
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("This is to confirm that this ever gets called"); // When I check the console, this text never appears
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("admin").password("password").roles("USER");
    }

}
```

My login form looks like this;

```
<form method="post" action="/admin/account/login">
    <label>Username</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="username"><br>
    <br>
    <label>Password</label><br>
    <input type="password" name="password"><br>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Login">
</form>
```

Is anyone able to explain why this isn't working as it should? Have I missed something?

To add, there is nothing in the console to indicate that there were any issues during compilation or running.

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to resolve this although I'm not certain how exactly.

I started by changing my security config to this (I added permitAll() for /admin/account/**;

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/admin/account/**").permitAll();
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
        http
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/admin/account/login")
                .passwordParameter("password")
                .usernameParameter("username")
                .failureUrl("/admin/account/login?error")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/admin/dashboard")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .logout()
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/admin/account/logout"))
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/admin/account/login");

        http.exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/admin/account/forbidden");
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("admin").password("password").roles("USER");
    }

}
```

Next my login form was using Thymeleaf, and I hadn't included the correct Doctype, so the forms action may not have been correct, hence why I was being redirected by the login page all of the time. Once I updated the security configuration the login page was redirecting me to /admin/account/forbidden (as it should), which indicated to me there was an issue.

My final login form looks like this;

```
<!DOCTYPE html SYSTEM "http://www.thymeleaf.org/dtd/xhtml1-strict-thymeleaf-4.dtd">
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Login</h1>

<form method="post" th:action="@{/admin/account/login}">
    <label>Username</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="username"><br>
    <br>
    <label>Password</label><br>
    <input type="password" name="password"><br>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Login">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```